# Trying to do a Fresh installation of the magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, php-5.6

After enabling the local.xml in the pub folder I got the below error

```
Missing required argument $routerList of Magento\Framework\App\RouterList.
```

I tried everything which is mentioned in the link 
[in github magento2 issues](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5031)

but still experiencing the same issue. Any guidance will be of greate help.

Comment: How did you install it ? Via the web setup wizard ? composer ? github ?

Comment: github, with all the system file privilages, I'm using vagrant dev environment.